# Why is template name available in derived class (the base class is an instance of the template)?

Tags: c++, templates, using

I came across this code (simplified with basic types):

```
template <typename T>
class Base {
  T t;
};

class Derived : public Base<short> {
 public:
  using Base<short>::Base;
};

int main() {
  Derived::Base<long long> x;
  printf("%lu\n", sizeof(x));
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and works (output is 8, which is the size of long long). It seems I can get `Base<T>` for any type `T` using `Derived::Base`, even if `Derived` is just a subclass of `Base<short>`. (In the code I came across, `Base` itself is not visible to `main`.)

However, I don't quite understand this grammar and why it works.

Is `Derived::Base` a template name, or a class, or a function (ctor)? It seems like a template name. Is the template name available in all classes that instantiate this template (like template name `Base` is in `Base<T>` for all type `T`)? I'm so confused. Any explanation or pointer to cppreference or the C++ standard are appreciated.

Comment: I think Derived::Base makes you create a Base type and not a Dervied ones :)

Comment: It's both a template name and a class. Depending how you use it.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#1.sentence-2

Comment: @cpplearner if you know the answer, you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [en.cppreference.com/injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name):

> In the following cases, the injected-class-name is treated as a template-name of the class template itself:
>
> - it is followed by <
> - [..]

So `Base` inside `Base<T>` is, depending of context, a class or a template name.